# How do I install physical copy of World of Warcraft without an optical disc drive?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I bought a WoW Legion DVD online but just realised my PC doesn't have a DVD reader. Does this come with a game key to install online or do I have to use the disc?

[image: A photo of a box containing physical copy of World of Warcraft: Legion.]

Comment: ...do people really still use these gift plastic scare-birds to install software?

Comment: There are many reasons that DVDs are preferable to internet downloads. Obviously not for this poster, but for many the DVD is a better option. Specially in rural areas or places where ISPs charge for data transferred.

Comment: @coteyr yours is a perfectly valid point and true for several edge cases, but you will admit that it sounds a bit silly when talking _precisely_ about an MMORPG :P

Comment: @xDaizu Why does it sound silly, WOW only requires a "low latency connecting greater then 28.8k"  The important part is the low latency not the amount of data that is transferred. Actually playing the game is "Very low data usage." Many people play from a cell phone on 3G networks. https://eu.battle.net/forums/en/wow/topic/5848175614#post-8 But you certainly would not want to install that way. The point is playing wow only takes a small chunk of data compared to installing wow.

Comment: You've asked four low quality question in a row. I'd highly recommend taking our tour and understanding what Arqade is all about. We have a very select standard, and opinionated questions are very frowned upon. By taking our tour, you will learn how to meet those standards, and prevent the system from automatically revoking your ability to ask questions.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use the CD/DVD key on the official website to play the game. You don't need the CD/DVD itself in any way.

In fact, by using the CD/DVD for an MMORPG, the installation process may take you longer than simply downloading the game in the first place, because the CD/DVD likely has outdated data on it, as most online games are frequently updating themselves with new patches and expansions that you will need to end up downloading anyway.

In the current year of 2017, you can also download & play the game for free without any CD/DVD Key & without even finishing the entire download of the game, but in that case you will have limitations on what you can do, including not being able to level past a certain point, and not being able to do certain quests or visit certain areas. In the future this may change and more limitations may be lifted on free accounts.

Comment: It will probably be faster, too. Even though your common DVD 16x drive reads at 21 MB/s, I somehow found it faster and more comfortable to download it even witha a low/mid range internet connection speed(10-50Mb/s). Also, you don't have to swap discs. Also, the first update will probably be way smaller :)

Comment: As an added bonus, you can start playing the game even before it's finished downloading thanks to Blizzard's streaming installation stuff.

Comment: You can actually download the game without the CD key - you just need the blizzard launcher formerly known as battle net, and there's a way to start the download even if you don't own the account.